# "COLUMNS_UPDATED" in SQLite triggers

Tags: sqlite, reference, triggers

I need a trigger to log updates on a table. As I want to log it I need to know the name of the updated column(s) in the trigger body. We have NEW and OLD but it doesn't tell me which column were updated.

If nothing else, I still have the choice between these two ugly solutions:

- use one IF NEW.val <> OLD.val per column
- use one trigger per column

*PS: I saw this "COLUMNS_UPDATED" in SQL which represents what I am looking for.*